# CORS issue with React + Quarkus + Auth0

Tags: reactjs, cors, quarkus, auth0

I have a Quarkus Backend + React Frontend + Auth0 for Authentication & Authorization. Here is how its setup:

**Auth0**

I have created an Application (setup as a Single Page Application) and set the following options. My frontend is running at: `localhost:3000` and the backend at: `locahost:8080`

- Allowed Callback URLs: `http://localhost:3000/callback`
- Allowed Logout URLs: `http://localhost:3000`
- Allowed Web Origins: `http://localhost:3000`
- Allowed Origins (CORS): `http://localhost:3000`

I also have setup an API, and set its `audience` in my Quarkus `application.properties` file (details given below). I have setup the `create:manager` permission in the API settings, and given this permission to the User Role `admin`.

**Quarkus**

I followed the [Quarkus OIDC Guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-web-authentication) which shows how to connect Quarkus with Keycloak, but since both Auth0 and Keycloak are OIDC providers, so I'm guessing it should be pretty similar.

My `application.properties` file contains:

```
quarkus.http.cors=true

quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu.auth0.com
quarkus.oidc.client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app
quarkus.oidc.token.audience=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I'm trying to create a `Manager` Resource on my backend but that can only be created by a user who has the `create:manager` permission which is given to `admin` User role in Auth0.

My Controller looks like this:

```java
@Path("/rest/manager")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ManagerController {

    ...

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    public Manager createManager(@Valid ManagerView managerView) {
        return managerService.createManager(managerView);
    }
}
```

**React**

On the frontend, I'm using React and Redux. I'm using the [Auth0 React](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react) library. I opted for using the react library instead of the js library because its easier to integrate.

I have wrapped my App with the `Auth0Provider`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Auth0ProviderWithHistory>
    <App />
  </Auth0ProviderWithHistory>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

In my redux action, I pass, the user token:

```
const EditableManagerRow = (props) => {
  const {getAccessTokenSilently} = useAuth0()
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  ...
  
  return (
    <TableRow>
      ...
      <RowEditButtons
        onSave={async () => {
          const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently()
          dispatch(managerOperations.addManager({manager: updatedManager, accessToken}))
        }}
        />
    </TableRow>
  )
```

The dispatch action makes the request with the following headers:

```
      .post<T>(url, params, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
```

This request goes to the backend. However, I'm getting the following CORS error in the browser:

```
XHR OPTIONS https://dev-8eki3hqn4jblufe6.eu.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=OXaPjK3H8Agz3VwsQ1oJbxIhwl1XoHWP&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/rest/manager&state=eaf3f4ec-8835-41f4-94d2-61c9e28177ff
CORS Missing Allow Origin

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://dev-8eki3hqn4jblufe6.eu.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=OXaPjK3H8Agz3VwsQ1oJbxIhwl1XoHWP&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Frest%2Fmanager&state=eaf3f4ec-8835-41f4-94d2-61c9e28177ff. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 404.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://dev-8eki3hqn4jblufe6.eu.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=OXaPjK3H8Agz3VwsQ1oJbxIhwl1XoHWP&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Frest%2Fmanager&state=eaf3f4ec-8835-41f4-94d2-61c9e28177ff. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

**What I have tried:**

- Setting Allowed Origins (CORS): `http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:8080`
- Setting Allowed Callback URLs: `http://localhost:3000/callback, http://localhost:8080`
- Different `application.properties` settings for CORS such as:

```
quarkus.http.cors.origins=http://localhost:3000
quarkus.http.cors.headers=accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with, Access-Control-Allow-Origin
quarkus.http.cors.methods=GET,OPTIONS,POST
quarkus.http.cors.exposed-headers=Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Authorization
```

However, nothing seems to work. I will be very grateful for any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue, Thanks to this [demo](https://blog.zenika.com/2021/06/01/securisation-oauth2-dune-single-page-application/).

The problem was that I was using: `quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app` in my `application.properties` file. I changed that to `quarkus.oidc.application-type=service` which is the default option, so you can actually just remove this line. Quarkus behaves differently based on this variable.